# pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np waits 100ms longer than it should

Tags: ios, xcode, pthreads

I've encountered some behavior from `pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np` that I can't really explain, and I was hoping someone might know what's happening.

Take the following code sample that times out after 100 ms.

```
struct timespec rtime1, rtime2, ts;
int ret;
uint32_t timeout = 100;
get_monotonic_time(&rtime1);
ts.tv_sec = timeout / 1000L;
ts.tv_nsec = (timeout % 1000L) * 1000000L;
printf("relative_np %ld\n", timeout);
ret = pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np(cond, mutex, &ts);
if (ret == ETIMEDOUT) {
 get_monotonic_time(&rtime2);
 ts.tv_sec = rtime2.tv_sec - rtime1.tv_sec;
 ts.tv_nsec = rtime2.tv_nsec - rtime1.tv_nsec;
 if (ts.tv_nsec < 0) {
   ts.tv_sec--;
   ts.tv_nsec += 1000000000L;
 }
 printf("waited %ld\n", ts.tv_sec * 1000L + ts.tv_nsec / 1000000L);
 return SYS_ARCH_TIMEOUT;
}
```

On the iPhone 6s, iOS 10 simulator in Xcode, this prints

```
relative_np 100
waited 100
```

But on the iPhone 5s, iOS 9 simulator, it prints

```
relative_np 100
waited 200
```

In fact, it consistently waits twice as long as it should. What could account for this, and is there a way to fix it? Should the timeout be set to half the expected value to correct for it? Is there a reason it changes from iOS to another?

edit: I've figured out more to this puzzle, though I'm maybe more confused than ever.

First, it's not twice as long, it's 100ms longer than it should. Just so happens that what I was testing waited 100ms. But if I wait 5ms, I see a wait of 105ms.

Second, using the same simulator (device and iOS version), I don't get this behavior in a brand new project - the wait occurs for the right length. That would suggest to me that it's somehow caused by something happening in my project. Except, when I create a new test suite in my existing project without including my project header file or calling any of its code, it still happens.

The only way this would seem possible to me is if simply loading my project somehow causes this? It's hard for me to imagine how that could be possible though.

Comment: Is there a manpage link or similar you can share? Then we can compare expected, documented behavior with the normal pthread_cond_timedwait and give some advice.

Comment: Not that I can find, no. I'd love to find one.

Comment: But how can you use an API without docs? Did you look at the API source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Xcode's Framework tester is just broken when testing iOS 9 and lower.

Demonstrating this is easy. Just create a new Cocoa Touch Framework, set deployment target to iOS 9 and then add unit tests. Paste this into the test and run it.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@interface timewait : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation timewait

static void get_monotonic_time(struct timespec *ts)
{
  struct timeval boottime;
  int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
  size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
  sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0);

  struct timeval now;
  gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

  uint64_t now_micro = now.tv_usec + (1000000 * now.tv_sec);
  uint64_t boot_micro = boottime.tv_usec + (1000000 * boottime.tv_sec);
  uint64_t diff_micro = now_micro - boot_micro;

  ts->tv_nsec = (diff_micro % 1000000) * 1000;
  ts->tv_sec = diff_micro / 1000000;
} 

- (void)testTimedWait {
  uint32_t timeout = 5;

  struct timespec rtime1, rtime2, ts;
  int ret;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    get_monotonic_time(&rtime1);

    printf("sleeping for %u\n", timeout);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(timeout / 1000.)];
    get_monotonic_time(&rtime2);
    ts.tv_sec = rtime2.tv_sec - rtime1.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = rtime2.tv_nsec - rtime1.tv_nsec;
    if (ts.tv_nsec < 0) {
      ts.tv_sec--;
      ts.tv_nsec += 1000000000L;
    }
    printf("waited %ld\n", ts.tv_sec * 1000L + ts.tv_nsec / 1000000L);

  }
}
@end
```

No matter what you set the timeout value to, the sleep seems to last about 100ms longer. Run the tests against an iOS 10 target and the discrepancy goes away.